# dark mode in tailwindcss with adonisjs project not working

Tags: tailwind-css, adonis.js

I'm using TailwindCSS 2, vue 3, in an adonisjs project.
I have a simple html button, which when clicked should toggle to dark mode on/off.
If I use the tailwindcss cdn version, and set darkmode in the config in the html, everything works fine. If I use my css, it doesn't. I guess I'm missing some step.

My tailwind.config.js does have the darkMode: 'class' definition

```
    content: ["./resources/**/*.{edge,js,ts,jsx,tsx,vue}"],
    darkMode : 'class',
    options: {
      safelist: ['dark']
    },
```

I prepare the css using the command:

```
    npx tailwindcss -i resources/css/style.css -o resources/css/app.css
```

I load the asset using adonisjs assets

```
    <link href="{{asset('assets/css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

when I click in the button, I can see that the html tag now has the "dark" class, but nothing happens. The background does not change. The body tag has "dark:bg-slate-800" definition.

But like I said, if I use the cdn version, everything works.

Am I missing a configuration step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue doing a few things:

- reinstalled the packages described here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/adonisjs (maybe I had missed something)
- moved my css to app.css
- added an style entry point in webpack.congfig.js:

  ```
    Encore.addStyleEntry('style', './resources/css/app.css')
  ```
- now I load my css using:

  ```
      @entryPointStyles('style')
  ```

now when I run "npm run dev" I guess tailwind is run under the hood by webpack and everything is working